# Trouble when generating an array of random values

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm generating an array of random numbers, between 0 and 2 with this code:

```
    for ($j = 0; $j < 60; $j++) {
       for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
                $value = rand(0,2);
                $DBH->query("INSERT INTO map (x, y, value) VALUES($i, $j, $value);");
    }
```

And i found and oddity, as you may see here, the rows are random, but they repeat:

```
22121000210211220022122200120200122000122121
22121000210211220022122200120200122000122121
22121000210211220022122200120200122000122121
22121000210211220022122200120200122000122121
22121000210211220022122200120200122000122121
```

How can avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to explicitly seed your generator using [srand](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php), e.g. `srand(time())` (note that the srand link has a better example of seeding than just using time, depends on how random you need, I suppose).

Failing that

- You could try using [mt_rand](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) with [mt_srand](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)
- You could always use MySQL's [rand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function to generate the numbers as a workaround.

Comment: Just saw this interesting comparison on mt_rand: http://portfolio.technoized.com/notes/26